# Print Progress bar value to textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to print a progressbar's percentage to a textbox. When ever I run my program, nothing appears in the textbox. This is my code:

```
    Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub
```

Help is very appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: The relevant parts of your code should **always** be posted **directly** in your question according to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apart from that, have you thought of using a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) to constantly update your TextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that i have written up for you to have a look at, it should lead you in the right direction and help you on your way :)

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
''This will display the information to the textbox and will also load a progressbar(you can change it to something else beside a textbox too eg label, windows form title and so on).
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    TextBox1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage & "%"
    ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ''This is make the backgroundworker start at load up(change it to a button if need be
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    ''This is the example that i created to show you how to set a task.
    For i = 0 To 10000
        TextBox1.Text = i
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Next
    End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    ''once the task is complete it will show a messagebox and reset the progressbars value to 0 so its not full when the task is compelete.
    MessageBox.Show("Completed")
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
End Sub
```

End Class

Let me know how you go, i live in a country where i cant access the website link that you posted.
Happy Coding

UPDATE: do check out the backgroundworkers on google, there are a lot of tutorials to help you :)